# Set Python dict items recursively, when given a compound key 'foo.bar.baz'

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I'd like to achieve the following:

```
foodict['foo.bar.baz'] = 'foo'
{
   'foo': {
      'bar': {
            'baz': 'foo'
         }
       }
   }
}
```

...creating keys recursively.

After scratching my head for a while, I've come up with this:

```py
class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.super = super(Config, self)
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, keys, value):
        keys   = keys.split('.')
        keys.reverse()

        config = Config()

        for i, k in enumerate(keys):
            if i == 0:
                config  = Config(**{ k: value })
            else:
                config  = Config(**{ k: config })

        self.super.update(config)
```

Comment: Do you mean: `{ 'foo': { 'bar': {'baz': 'foo' } }}`?

Comment: My Bad, updated the question.

Comment: The trickery with `enumerate(keys)` and then recursing and handling the first key differently is clever but seems seriously non-obvious and arms'-length recursion. Why don't you just override `YourRecursiveDictClass.__setitem__()` to take an optional list of keys, and recurse accordingly? Then call with `foodict[(['foo','bar','baz'])]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might consider the "infinite defaultdict" recipe, from Raymond Hettinger himself:

https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/343823801278140417

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> infinite_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(infinite_defaultdict)
>>> d = infinite_defaultdict()
>>> d['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'foo'
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1040388c8>, {'foo': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1040388c8>, {'bar': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1040388c8>, {'baz': 'foo'})})})
```

Another option is to implement `__missing__`:

```
>>> class InfiniteDict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, val):
...         d = InfiniteDict()
...         self[val] = d
...         return d
...
>>> d = InfiniteDict()
>>> d['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'foo'
>>> d
{'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 'foo'}}}
```

And if you must have attribute access:

```
class InfiniteDict(dict):
   def __missing__(self, val):
       d = InfiniteDict()
       self[val] = d
       return d
   def __getattr__(self, item):
       return self.__getitem__(item)
   def __setattr__(self, item, value):
       super().__setitem__(item, value)
```

In action:

```
>>> d = InfiniteDict()
>>> d.foo.bar.baz = 'foo'
>>> d
{'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 'foo'}}}
>>>
```

Although, that's a little quick-and-dirty, so no guarantees there aren't any bugs. And there are very little guards against, for example, collisions with actual attributes:

```
>>> d.keys = 'should I be allowed?'
>>> d
{'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 'foo'}}, 'keys': 'should I be allowed?'}
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['foo', 'keys'])
```

Comment: Do you think there's a better way of declaring them (like the dot separator used) with a combination of `__setitem__` overridden?

Comment: I think I'll go ahead with this! It's just a matter of creating another helper function to achieve the above (keys declared with dots) - Somewhat like a JS object.

Comment: @AchillesGasperRasquinha sure

Comment: @AchillesGasperRasquinha added an implementation with `__setitem__` overridden